# What is the error in my code of c++? Leetcode Q.922 Sort Array By Parity II

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, debugging

Dry run of the given code is giving the right output, but the code is not giving correct output on Leetcode.
Question Link : https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-array-by-parity-ii
My code:

```
vector<int> sortArrayByParityII(vector<int>& nums) {
    int n=size(nums);
    int even=n-2;
    int odd=n-1;
        while(odd>=0 && even>=0){
            if((nums[0])/2==0){
                int temp=nums[0];
                nums[0]=nums[even];
                nums[even]=temp;
                even=even-2;
                
            }        
            else if(nums[0]/2!=0){
                int temp=nums[0];
                nums[0]=nums[odd];
                nums[odd]=temp;
                odd=odd-2;
                
            }
        }
    return nums;
}
```

Comment: If you're checking for even/odd `(nums[0])/2==0` should be `(nums[0]) % 2==0`. You should use the modulo operator.

Comment: I guess you did a dry run on an array of even number of  integers. Dry run with an array of odd no. of integers e.g. [1,2,3,4,5] and you will see that logic isn't correct.